# How to make a scrollable fragment based on the default android PageView

Tags: java, android

I am using the default setup from the PageView setup in Android. I want to stay very simple. The default setup provides a TextView to put text in, and my text goes off the screen. Is it possible to make this scroll vertically?

```
// edited to make the code appear in the code block
public class DayFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public DayFragment() {

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Create a new TextView and set its text to the fragment's section
        // number argument value.
        TextView tView = new TextView(getActivity());
        if(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER) > 1){
            tView.setText(getAllMeals(getArguments().getInt(
                    ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)-1));}
        else {
            getMeal();
            tView.setText(message);
        }
        return tView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes it is very simple, in your xml layout file just make the parent a `ScrollView` of whatever you want to be scrollable.

`ScrollView` reference doc:http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html

Edit sample:
Here is a sample of your XML.

```xml
...rest of xml
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
 </ScrollView> ...rest of xml
```

Then to get the TextView in your Activity just

```
TextView tView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview);
```

2nd Edit:
Edited above sample for a regular scrollview. Also to add the swiping functionality, you will want to use a a ViewPager(http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) and a FragmentPagerAdapter(http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html). The 2 links to official developer documents contain really great examples!

Comment: That is easy. I was wondering if it's possible to do this in the pre-made fragment as shown above. You see how the Java code makes the TextView? I can make a ScrollView using the same method, but when I try to assign the TextView as it's child, it says that TextView already has a parent.

Comment: Yeah, just create your ScrollView: `ScrollView scrollView = new ScrollView(getActivity());` Then add you textView to it: `scrollView.addView(tView);` Just wondering though, any reason you are trying to build your interface in Java, as opposed to defining the the layout in xml?

Comment: If you have a good example on how to do that with side-scrolling, I would love it. And, if I try to add tView to the ScrollView, it tells me that tView already has a parent.

Comment: Thanks! That's a great example.

Comment: You're very welcome, @sjoshua270! If this is what you wanted, could you please mark the post as useful and accept the answer? Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not give me a solution to paging left and right

Comment: It is letting me scroll left and right, but it's not a paged view. I need to scroll left and right between 7 lists (days of the week) and display different content under each one. Those lists need to scroll.

Comment: @sjoshua270, so you are trying to scroll left in inside a page, but also scroll left and right between fragments?

Comment: No, it's just a normal setup with 7 fragments. Each fragment has text that scrolls up and down with a ScrollView. Very simple, just that I'm a beginner in this stuff, and need some sample code to get started.

Comment: @sjoshua270, ok now I know what you want to do, I have edited my answer for that purpose.

Answer (score 2):

it is also possible to wrap the entire layout in `fragment.xml` in a `ScrollView` , see [How to add scroll in Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40562344/how-to-add-scroll-in-fragment/43188084#43188084). this is also  XML based ...