# How to add scroll in Fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-fragments, twitter

I have implemented `Twitter SDK` in a List Fragment. It has unlimited scroll just like twitter. But when i try to add this Fragment in a `scrollview layout` it disables `scrollview` of `twitter fragment`.

```
public class TwitterFragment extends ListFragment {
    public static TwitterFragment newInstance() {
        return new TwitterFragment();
    }
```

**Layout**

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@id/android:empty"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:text="No Tweets" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:divider="#e1e8ed"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Now i want to add this Fragment in another activity. `MainActivity` has already a scroll view. when i add this fragment there, the scroll of twitter fragment is gone. I tried various ways, but failed to achieve the target.

I need the same unlimited scroll in the small fragment as well.

This is my `MainActivity` Code.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/content_users_feedback"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.myapp.app.usersreviews.reviews"
    android:background="@drawable/users_bg"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_user_reviews">



    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:isScrollContainer="false"
        android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
        android:layout_below="@+id/sv_users"
        >


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >


            <!-- USER DATA-->
            <include layout="@layout/users_data_list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/layout_data"

                />



            <!-- TWITTER-->

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView8"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="33.62dp"
                android:background="#054F92"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="\@tweets"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                android:textStyle="normal|bold" />


                <fragment
                    android:id="@+id/cart_twitter_fragment"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginTop="-50dp"
                    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
                    class="com.myapp.app.TwitterFragment"
                    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_twitter" />


            <!-- TWITTER -->


        </LinearLayout> 

    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Just to confirm, does the user data list contain so much data that it needs to scroll as well?

Comment: @clownba0t , yes it has a lot of data, i have not added all  the views in the questions

Comment: My understanding is that nesting `ScrollView`s is generally not advised, at least in part because it can be difficult to determine which of them should handle any given swipe gesture. It seems you're encountering this very issue. I'd recommend changing the way the data is presented. Consider moving the `ScrollView` in your activity layout so that it only wraps the user data list. That way you have two scroll layouts but they're not nested. Then you can set the width, height, weight, etc. of the fragment and that scroll view to achieve the desired UI, while still permitting both to scroll.

Answer (score 11):

you can add a `ScrollView` in the `fragment_layout.xml` that wraps the entire layout (a *ScrollView* normally has one child, in this case the entire layout defined in `fragment_layout.xml`). The `View` is then generated normally by the layout inflater

**fragment.java :**

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);
return view;
```

in the following example of a `fragment_layout.xml` with a *ScrollView* the *ScrollView* wraps a `ConstraintLayout` that contains two TextViews

**fragment_layout.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.ralf.gpstelephony.TelephonyManagerFragment">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView_1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="600dp"
        android:text="@string/string1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"  />

 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView_2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="600dp"
        android:text="@string/string2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/TextView1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/TextView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"  />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

when using this method the `LayoutInflater` does all the work, one does not have to create an instance of *ScrollView* in `fragment.java` (xml based method)